# How do I remove one of two GitHub accounts on my terminal/computer?

Tags: windows, git, macos, github, terminal

I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/lLgWWtOk7gk) to have two GitHub accounts. I did this because I have a desktop PC and a Macbook laptop, both of which I use to code. Turns out that it was a nightmare managing two accounts. I faced problems such as:

1. Not being able to push changes on repositories
2. Encountering numerous repository errors which discouraged me from using Git or GitHub

which tells me that I should only have one account, and use the same account on both computers. So, my questions are:

1. Do I just erase the SSH keys for the account I don't want both of my
   computers in my GitHub account settings?
2. Or do I also have to
   remove the id_rsa_xxxxx.pub that I did for the account as well?
3. Do I also have to reconfigure my "git global" on the terminal (bash)?

I appreciate any input since I have not used Git properly since I did this :( Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that you have one Windows-specific answer; you may still need a macOS-specific answer depending on whether you've stored keys in the macOS keychain. (I don't, I use ssh and keep my mac setups the same as my Linux and BSD ones.)

Comment: Would you happen to know where to find the Mac SSH keys? Because, when I access "Keychain Access", I can't find my git accounts in the search :(

Comment: I just store mine in ~/.ssh/ directly (a la Linux and BSD). As I said, I don't use any of the Mac-specific stuff, so not sure where they go in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel -> credential Manager -> Windows Credentials. Find Git or GitHub, click on it, and press the remove button.

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I haven't completely solved my problem. I saw that I never actually registered another Git user on my PC, as I can only see one username in the Credentials Manager.